# Each Value of Array index which is zero is missed while printed?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, data-structures

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] starTime = { 1,2,5,9 };
    int[] relinqtime = { 2,4,8,9 };
    int[] resReqRAM= { 9,8,7,5 };
    int[] totalDuration = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    totalDuration[0] = 0;
    System.out.println(totalDuration[0]);            
    for(int j = 0; j < starTime.length; j++){
        for(int k = starTime[j]; k < relinqtime[j]; k++){
            totalDuration[k] += resReqRAM[j];
            System.out.println(totalDuration[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of above code as I expected **should be**

```
0
9
8
8
0
7
7
7
0
0
```

But the **actual printed output is**

```
0
9
8
8
7
7
7
```

Why in the output value of totalDuration[4], totalDuration[8], totalDuration[9] is missed  which should be printed as 0?

Comment: use a Debugger, to find it out

Comment: Format *and finish* your code first.

Comment: @Jens Debugger too skips the value when it comes to  totalDuration[4]

Comment: Give us the rest of the code.

Comment: @ПетърПетров this is it

Comment: You need to put same amount of effort into your question as you would like to see in an answer. Your code was unacceptably formatted. I fixed it as much as I could but you still have a lingering `}` which I commented out. That'll be the last time I do it for you.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks for that but My issue is not a compile time error rather why the value of totalDuration[4], totalDuration[8],totalDuration[9] is not printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output for you given code is the one below and not the one you stated.

```
0 9 8 8 7 7 7 7  12
```

Format your code in a better manner and take a look inside whats happening inside the nested for loop.

Add the below code outside your 2 for loops to get the desired output you want

```
for(int i=0; i<totalDuration.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println( totalDuration[i]);
        }
```

You were trying to print only the changed elements of the totalDuration array, while expecting the entire array to be printed. To get the output as `0 9 8 8 0 7 7 7 0 0` , you need to print the entire array.

Comment: No, the one you stated would be if System.out.println(totalDuration[0]) would be inside the for( int j =0; j<starTime.length;j++) loop. Its outside...so the one i stated is correct.

Comment: I suggest you take a look again. I checked with your code.

Comment: I have checked it twice, its still the same.

Comment: @sjs :Made the edit in my original post. Make the changes if needed.

Comment: That is smart. Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Print your array at end, your are printing array in the loop where the value of k in the second for loop is never 4, so it is not printing `t[4]`, same goes with other indexes.

The output mentioned in the question is not correct.

The correct output is `[0, 9, 8, 8, 0, 7, 7, 7, 12, 0]`

[Check here](http://ideone.com/gwfaEw)

Suggestion : Put a debug point at first for loop and note down the indexes (j and k).

Comment: That helped.  You might have picked up the code before I edited. The present code gives the output i stated, your one is also right. The main issue was to print the value which solved anyways. Thanks. Can you please tell me whats  Arrays.toString does?

Comment: @Sjs Arrays.toString just returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
For more Information [check here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_tostring_int.htm)